# Only Show Clear Button in p-calendar Component

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to only have a Clear button on the p-calendar component.

**myComponent.html**

```
<p-calendar
  value="#{property.propDate}" id="date"
  [showIcon]="true"
  [utc]='true'
  placeholder="{{ timePickerPlaceHolder }}"
  [showTransitionOptions]="'100ms'"
  [hideTransitionOptions]="'100ms'"
  [inputStyle]="{ width: '248px' }"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  [defaultDate]="defaultDate"
  showTime="true"
  [readonlyInput]="true"
  hourFormat="24"
  showButtonBar="true"
  [todayButtonStyleClass]="'today-button'"
  [timeOnly]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

**myComponent.less**

```
.today-button {
  display: none !important
}
```

But this does nothing. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
::ng-deep.ui-datepicker-buttonbar > div.ui-g div:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Of course this is related with your html code of the button for p-calendar.
Good luck